# Passing a list of values to kernel space

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, gnu, kmalloc

I'm working on a linux project. I need to pass a list of integer values to the kernel from a userspace program. I implemented a system call for this. In the userspace program, I had the following code. The value of `num_values` is obtained from command line arguments.

```
int* ptr=NULL;
    ptr = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*num_values);

    for(loop_index=0;loop_index<num_values;loop_index++)
    {
        *(ptr+loop_index)=atoi(argv[optind+loop_index]);
    }
```

Then, I called my system call,

```
        ret = set_wcet_val(ptr,&num_values);
```

The syscall '`set_wcet_val`' implementation in the kernel is as follows:

```
asmlinkage long sys_set_wcet_val(int* wcet_val, int* num_values)
{
    int retval=0, retval2=0, index, loop_index;
    int *wcet_ptr=NULL;
    retval2 = get_user(index,(int*)num_values);
    wcet_ptr = kmalloc(((sizeof(int))*index), GFP_ATOMIC);
    if(!wcet_ptr)
            printk("kmalloc:Error in allocating space..\n");
    if (copy_from_user(wcet_ptr, wcet_val, sizeof(wcet_ptr)))
    {
            printk("Syscall-wcet_val failed to copy data..\n");
    }
    for(loop_index=0;loop_index<index;loop_index++)
            printk("wcet_ptr value is %d\n",*(wcet_ptr+loop_index));
    kfree(wcet_ptr);
    return retval;
```

}

The value '`num_values`' is properly copied to '`index`'. 
The problem is only the first two data are printed when I checked `dmesg`.
If the `num_values` is 3, I'm getting a random positive value for the third data.
If the `num_values` is 4, a random positive value for third and a negative value for fourth data.
For `num_values` > 4, all values from third data are zero.
In all cases, only the first two values are copied correctly.
What is the reason for this weird behaviour ?

Comment: 99.9% of the time, writing a new system call is the wrong way to do what you're trying to do. Are you sure there aren't any other kernel facilities that will fit your purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least correct the `copy_from_user` call (to copy the entire `index` entries):

```
asmlinkage long sys_set_wcet_val(int* wcet_val, int* num_values)
{
    int retval=0, retval2=0, index, loop_index;
    int *wcet_ptr=NULL;
    retval2 = get_user(index,(int*)num_values);
    wcet_ptr = kmalloc(((sizeof(int))*index), GFP_ATOMIC);
    if(!wcet_ptr)
            printk("kmalloc:Error in allocating space..\n");
    if (copy_from_user(wcet_ptr, wcet_val, (sizeof(int))*index))
    {
            printk("Syscall-wcet_val failed to copy data..\n");
    }
    for(loop_index=0;loop_index<index;loop_index++)
            printk("wcet_ptr value is %d\n",*(wcet_ptr+loop_index));
    kfree(wcet_ptr);
    return retval;
}
```

It would be better to pass `num_values` directly, instead of a pointer to it (unless you had to modify it somehow):

```
asmlinkage long sys_set_wcet_val(int* wcet_val, int num_values)
{
    int retval=0, loop_index;
    int *wcet_ptr=NULL;
    wcet_ptr = kmalloc(((sizeof(int))*num_values), GFP_ATOMIC);
    if(!wcet_ptr)
            printk("kmalloc:Error in allocating space..\n");
    if (copy_from_user(wcet_ptr, wcet_val, (sizeof(int))*num_values))
    {
            printk("Syscall-wcet_val failed to copy data..\n");
    }
    for(loop_index=0;loop_index<num_values;loop_index++)
            printk("wcet_ptr value is %d\n",*(wcet_ptr+loop_index));
    kfree(wcet_ptr);
    return retval;
}
```

Call it as `ret = set_wcet_val(ptr, num_values);`.

But I think the best you could do is to get rid of a syscall and use a kobject instead. Look for `kobject_create_and_add`, `sysfs_create_group`, `struct attribute_group`.